# In Eclipse, I do not have add 'plugin' in the add new project wizard

Tags: java, android, eclipse, plugins

I downloaded the Eclipse ADT Bundle for android from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) - my help/about ADT says: Android Developer Tools - Build: v22.2.1-833290 - This product includes Eclipse Platform, JDT, CDT, EMF, GEF and WTP.

Now I need to add a plugin according to the tutorials [here](http://hsapkota.com.au/index.php/blog/eclipse/22-creating-eclipse-plugins-from-any-jar-archives-or-existing-frameworks).

When I chose File / New / Project, I do not see any plugin to create a new Eclipse plugin project from existing JAR archives.

How can I add support for adding plugins in my Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the Plug-in Development Environment, PDE.